# After upgrading to IOS 5 ipod is not detected by ubuntu 10.04 anymore

Tags: ipod

I updated my iPod to iOS 5 and now Ubuntu 10.04 does not even mount it anymore, the version of `libimobiledevice` is 1.0.6-1, and I also tried the unpair/pair routine but it did not fix my problem, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it doesn't show up under 10.04 is because with the iOS5 upgrade, Apple changed the way it talks to computers, and due to the fact that 10.04 is an LTS, it is highly unlikely that it'll get an update to "fix" it.

However, it **does** mount under 11.10 - if using 11.10 is an option, that is the solution.

Comment: thank you jrg see this why ubuntu / Linux is never going to get any where people should NOT have to mess around looking all over the place to make a iphone that is in the hands of millions of people just work no excuses no messing it should be just working people don't want to have a big discussion on the inner workings of the os it should just work I can't advice people to use ubuntu while this silly none sense exists. Plug in iphone then it should show on the desktop or places nav to files end of very very poor.

Comment: @mee As soon as Apple starts cooperating like they do with other vendors this won't be a problem. Currently drivers for this have to be reverse engineered in order to work on Linux. Reverse engineered by volunteers. I understand your frustration, but please understand this isn't entirely the fault of Ubuntu

Comment: @mee, Marco is correct. This isn't Ubuntu's fault, in fact, it probably could be said that this isn't anyones fault except for the owner of the iOS device - Apple has said (by their silence) "This is a proprietary product, so we don't want to support anything other than iTunes, Windows and Mac" - and they have that right - there is no law that says "You have to make it work with Ubuntu, Mac and Windows".